# replace a particular value in a string of key - values

Tags: bash, string, sed, awk

I have a large string which is a collection of `key (space)+ value`, i.e `key` followed by one or more space and then `value`.
Now i need to change the `value` of a particular `key` using `sed, awk, grep` etc. in `unix` environment.

eg. of string: `-Key1       Value1    -Key2    Value2   -Key3  Value3`

I need a new string that is same as above only `Value2` will be replaced by `NewValue3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "-Key1 Value1 -Key2 Value2 -Key3 Value3" | \
    sed -r -e "s/(-Key2\s+)([^-\s]+)(\s+)/\1<newvale>\3/g"
-Key1 Value1 -Key2 <newvale> -Key3 Value3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(-Key2\)\(  *\)\([^ ]*\)\( .*\)/\1\2\3NewValue3\5/'
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "What is your key?: " key
read -p "What is new value?: " value
echo "-Key1 Value1 -Key2 Value2 -Key3 Value3" | awk -vk="$key" -vv="$value" -F"-"  '
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i ~ k){
            $i=k" "v" "
        }
    }
}1 ' OFS="-"

$ ./shell.sh
What is your key?: Key2
What is new value?: NewVal2
-Key1 Value1 -Key2 NewVal2 -Key3 Value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with bash:

```
str="-Key1 Value1 -Key2 Value2 -Key3 Value3"
set -- $str  # variable is not quoted to allow for word splitting
new=""
while [[ -n "$1" ]]
do
  case "$1" in
  -Key2) val="newval2" ;;
  *) val="$2" ;;
  esac
  new="$new $1 $val"
  shift 2
done
str="$new"
```